# How Hard reset removes everything but not removing *.zip file

Tags: android, rom, oneplusone

They tell Hard reset removes everything from our Android Phone then how is it keeping the custom-rom zip file after hard reset so that we can install the custom rom on to the device?

I didn't try but got the doubt when I am reading online on how to install Lineage-OS

Comment: hard-reset doesn't touch files in an *external* SD card

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, how about internal storage? All I see is oneplus One has only internal storage.

Comment: Maybe you didn't wipe the `/data` partition, only `/system`?

Comment: I added a sentence that I didn't do. All I see is from the posts online. So, I am curious to know how it works on internal storage.

The link that I am referring is: http://www.lineageosrom.com/2016/12/how-to-install-lineage-os-rom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard reset removes everything that you'd placed in internal memory, including the .zip file. The instructions you linked assumed having an sdcard available. If you don't, you'll need another method, for example, using adb to push the zip file to the device after you've done the reset and booted into the custom recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply got a clear picture. I will check online on how to push the zip file to the device using adb.

Comment: @Vamsi cool. Please accept the answer if you've confirmed it's correct.